# jquery - Get the Text Value after the anchor tag

Tags: jquery, text

I am new to jquery. Can someone please help me to get the name 'John' in following html. Thank you.

```
<td aria-expanded="true" style="height: 20px; background-color: rgb(237, 240, 245);" colSpan="4">
<p class="k-reset">
<a tabIndex="-1" class="k-icon k-i-collapse" href="#"/>
Text - Name: John
```

Comment: is anchor tag supports self closing???

Comment: Since when is self closing anchor tag is valid?!

Comment: can you add full html?

Comment: This anchor tag is being generated by third party UI controls (e.g. grid) . So I can not edit the anchor tag whether it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone but unfortunately nothing worked in my case and I ended up writing following:

```
  $(".k-reset").text().replace("Name: ", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a reference to the anchor element, (I don't think the below selector `a.k-i-collapse` is unique enough to uniquely identify the element)

```
var text = $('a.k-i-collapse').prop('nextSibling').nodeValue
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CR9g7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a tabIndex="-1" class="k-icon k-i-collapse" href="#">Text - Name: John</a>

console.log($(".k-icon").text());
```

Comment: This will return more than just "John".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var html = $('.k-icon.k-i-collapse').html();
html = html.replace("Text - Name:",""); 
alert(html);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Y9mG/25/

Comment: It is not inside anchor tag for what OP has asked.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar the anchor tag does not allow a `<a />` closing, so it wraps the text if it is the actual markup used

Comment: @ArunPJohny:so text content should either be inside a tag or just outside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var at = $('a.k-icon.k-i-collapse or fix your html').text()
var name = at.substr(at.indexOf(':') + 1, at.length);
```